# Is there a way to pass multiple arguments to menu_name while creating menu links programmatically?

Tags: 7, navigation

Am using Drupal 7.
Below is my code where am trying to create menu links programmatically:

```
$links[] = array(
'menu_name' => 'management',
'link_path' => 'myheader/config',
'link_title' => 'Header Settings',
'options' => array(),
'weight' => 2,
'parent' => 'custom/header-settings',
);
$links[] = array(
'menu_name' => 'mycustommenu',
'link_path' => 'myheader/config',
'link_title' => 'Header Settings',
'options' => array(),
'weight' => 2,
'parent' => 'custom/header-settings',
);
```

In the above code, only menu_name is different. Rest of them are same. Is there a way to pass multiple arguments to menu_name?

Answer (score 1):

No. When you're building links for [D7's menu system](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/group/menu/7.x), you'll need to specify the entire link array because you're creating link metadata here. If you're trying to keep your [code DRY](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/group/menu/7.x) you *could* try to create a template array (or function) then copy/update as you needed new links, but you're probably doing just as much work for little/no performance gain or clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to define some [menu links](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_link_save/7.x). You have to return an array with all menu links you want to define, and there's no way to define multiple menu links using a parameter or similar.

What you can do is to construct the array programmatically:

```
$link_template = array(

  'link_path' => 'myheader/config',
  'link_title' => 'Header Settings',
  'options' => array(),
  'weight' => 2,
  'parent' => 'custom/header-settings',
);

$menu_names = array('management', 'mycustommenu');

$links = [];

foreach ($menu_names as $menu_name) {
  $links[] = array('menu_name' => $menu_name) + $link_template;
}
```

This way you have only one array where you can modify menu properties (the `$link_template` variable), and a list where you can easily add new menu entries (`$menu_names` variable).

No performance gain, but menu properties are defined just once.